# How do I create a Power Automate custom connector via REST calls (like in Postman)?

Tags: rest, postman, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

Does anyone know if Power Automate exposes API's to let me create custom connectors through REST calls instead of the UI? I've scoured the internet and so far I only see creating and updating flows via REST.

I can't try anything because I don't know what URL's to call and the JSON payload I need to send.

Comment: I don’t believe it’s possible.

Comment: What's your use case?  Why would it be that you're wanting to create a custom connector through an API?  I ask because there may be another way to solve your problem.

Comment: Turns out only the CLI (paconn) can perform this as of now.  So I'll close the question. :D

Answer (score 0):

Turns out only the CLI (paconn) can perform this as of now. Hopefully in the future Microsoft will expose the API.